# Java calculator - loop through string array for character

Tags: java, calculator

I'm a programming beginner and I am creating a calculator in java but having trouble looping through the list2 array for a character, then converting to the character data type to run through the getToken method. Can someone help me please?

This is the getToken method...

```
    public Precedence getToken(char symbol)
{
    switch (symbol)
    {
        case '('  : return Precedence.lparen;
        case ')'  : return Precedence.rparen;
        case '+'  : return Precedence.plus;
        case '-'  : return Precedence.minus;
        case '/'  : return Precedence.divide;
        case '*'  : return Precedence.times;
        case '%'  : return Precedence.mod;
        case ' '  : return Precedence.eos;
        default   : return Precedence.operand;
    }
}
```

This is the postfix function

```
/** Function to convert infix to postfix **/

public String postfix(String infix)
{
    String postfix = "";
    top = 0;
    String s = infix.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
    //int p = infix.length();
    stack = new Precedence[infix.length()];
    stack[0] = Precedence.eos;
    String [] str = infix.split(" ");
    List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList(str);

    Precedence token;

    if (s.matches("[-+/*0-9]+[-+/*0-9]"))
    {
        System.out.println("true");
    }
    else
    {
        System.err.println("Invalid expression!");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < list2.size(); i++)
    {     
        if (list2.get(i).matches("\\p{Punct}"))
        {
            token = getToken(list2.get(i));
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the question, exactly?

Comment: How do I loop through the list2 array and if it's a character then convert it to the character data type?

Comment: Since you're validating the string for containing just one character, you can just get the character with `list2.get(i).charAt(0)`, and pass it to `getToken` method.

Comment: Or you can just use a `Map<String, Precedence>` and prefill it with mapping of tokens to `Precedence` objects, and get the needed `Precedence` with just `tokenMap.get(token)`, and additionally, if the argument is not one of the keys, return `Precedence.operand'.

Answer (score 1):

Your method take a `char` argument

```
public Precedence getToken(char symbol)
```

You're trying to pass a String to it

```
List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList(str);
...
token = getToken(list2.get(i));
```

---

**EDIT** as @ahanin pointed out to me, the list is an entire operation. In that case, his comment is correct, where you need to use `.charAt(0)`

```
token = getToken(list2.get(i).charAt(0));
```

Comment: Then the list won't be able to contain arguments, e.g. numbers, bigger than 9, or negative numbers.

Comment: @ahanin I see what you're saying. I didn't realize the list was a whole equation.